# Why wont this Sql statament 'order by' properly

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the sql:

```
SELECT t.TagText, COUNT(*) AS NumVidsWithTag 
FROM tbl_Tag t
INNER JOIN tbl_Video_Tag_Xref x ON t.TagId=x.TagId
INNER JOIN tbl_Video v ON x.VideoId=v.VideoId
WHERE 6 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_Video_Tag_Xref WHERE VideoId=6 AND TagId=t.TagId) 
GROUP BY t.TagText
```

Which returns:

```
1   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  1
14  1
15  1
16  1
17  1
18  1
19  1
2   1
20  1
```

Then I changed the sql to

```
SELECT t.TagText, COUNT(*) AS NumVidsWithTag 
FROM tbl_Tag t
INNER JOIN tbl_Video_Tag_Xref x ON t.TagId=x.TagId
INNER JOIN tbl_Video v ON x.VideoId=v.VideoId
WHERE 6 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_Video_Tag_Xref WHERE VideoId=6 AND TagId=t.TagId) 
GROUP BY t.TagText 
ORDER BY t.TagText ASC
```

And it still comes back as:

```
1   1
10  1
11  1
12  1
13  1
14  1
15  1
16  1
17  1
18  1
19  1
2   1
20  1
```

Im confused as to why this wont sort properly?

Comment: p.s the video id is just a replaced paramteer!

Comment: Why is the name `TagText` and not `TagNumber`? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is sorted properly.

TagText is a string, so "11" is 'smaller than' "2", for instance

To sort it numerically, change your ORDER BY to

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, t.TagText) ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like TagText is a varchar field, rather than a number. SQL will order varchar fields based on the rules for sorting text - Aa comes before B, so 19 comes before 2.

Answer (score 2):

Assumedly `tbl_Tag.TagText` columns datatype is `varchar` or something similar.

In which case, this is sorting correctly - sorting alphanumerically, 19 comes before 2; and 100 would come before 11.

You will need to change the datatype to a numeric type.

You will be able to do this without changing the schema of the table:

```
SELECT t.TagText, COUNT(*) AS NumVidsWithTag 
FROM tbl_Tag tINNER JOIN tbl_Video_Tag_Xref x ON t.TagId=x.TagId
    INNER JOIN tbl_Video v ON x.VideoId=v.VideoId
WHERE 6 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_Video_Tag_Xref WHERE VideoId=6 AND TagId=t.TagId) 
GROUP BY t.TagText 
ORDER BY CONVERT(int, t.TagText) ASC
```

Essentially, just change the ORDER BY clause to convert the TagText column to type `int`

Answer (score 2):

TagText is a character field (nvarchar?) and is being sorted alphanumerically.

You will need to convert it to numeric format in order to sort.

```
SELECT t.TagText, COUNT(*) AS NumVidsWithTag 
FROM tbl_Tag t
INNER JOIN tbl_Video_Tag_Xref x ON t.TagId=x.TagId
INNER JOIN tbl_Video v ON x.VideoId=v.VideoIdWHERE 6 IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_Video_Tag_Xref 
WHERE VideoId=6 AND TagId=t.TagId) 
GROUP BY t.TagText ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, t.TagText) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why because of the data type of column is not `integer`. it is string and sorted like string.

hence `2` comes after `19`

Possible solution is that: change the data type of your column to `integer`

Answer (score 1):

I assume t.TagText is a character field? The order will sorted using the ASCII values of this field. The above sort order is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's ordering wrong because the order column is a text (varchar/nvarchar). Try converting to a int in the select section of the sql.

Cast/Convert help here if needed
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx